# Scrolling up instead of down in vertical div container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I currently have HTML and CSS for a horizontally scrolling parallax site. However, I would like it so when you get to a specific section you're given a vertical parallax scroll instead of a horizontal one.

Check out this site for an example: http://paranorman.com/scene/normans-friends ...you'll see how the horizontal scroll, all of a sudden becomes a vertical scroll...

Check out this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L2MZe/

I currently have a horizontally scrolling parallax, with a vertical scrolling div nested inside of it...I'm not really sure how to make the div scroll up, instead of down though.

This is the code I'm using for my 'go-up' div:

```
#go-up {
background-color:blue;
width:650px;
left:3000px;
overflow-y: scroll;
height:100%;
overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Is there a way to make the 'go-up' div start at the bottom of its content (with JS or CSS)? This seems like the easiest way, but if there are other ways I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the scroll position to the bottom, you can use a little bit of jQuery/javascript:

```
// maximum vertical scroll
var maxScrollV = $('#go-up')[0].scrollHeight - $('#go-up').innerHeight();

// Set vertical scroller to bottom
$('#go-up').scrollTop(maxScrollV);
```

As far as doing the vertical scroll with a horizontal scroll bar, I would create a fake scroll bar that sits below the main content and make the main content `overflow: hidden` in both directions.  Then use jQuery and some math to use the position of the fake scroll bar to set the scroll position of the main content:

```
$('#main').stellar();

// maximum vertical scroll
var maxScrollV = $('#go-up')[0].scrollHeight - $('#go-up').innerHeight();

// Set vertical scroller to bottom
$('#go-up').scrollTop(maxScrollV);

// Maximum horizontal scroll of fake scroller
var maxScrollH = $('#scroller')[0].scrollWidth - $('#scroller').innerWidth();

// Whenever you move the fake scroller, update the content's scroll
$('#scroller').on('scroll', function () {
    // position of fake scroll bar
    var sL = $('#scroller').scrollLeft();
    if (sL < 3000) {
        // If not at the vertical scroller, just H-scroll
        $('#main').scrollLeft(sL);
    } else {
        // How far have we scrolled passed the vertical scroll point?
        var percScrollV = (sL-3000)/(maxScrollH-3000);

        // Make sure we only scroll to the vertical scroll point
        $('#main').scrollLeft(3000);

        // Do the vertical scroll
        $('#go-up').scrollTop( maxScrollV - (maxScrollV * percScrollV) );
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JD7Jc/1/

My demo here uses a fixed position for the vertical scroller (3000px) and an arbitrary width for the fake scroller but with a little more work, you could find the position automatically, as well as set the width according to some sensible calculation.

EDIT, Here is an example of that: http://jsfiddle.net/JD7Jc/2/

Comment: This is ridiculously impressive. Really wouldn't have thought of this on my own. Can't thank you enough!

Comment: Unfortunately, after using this method for a bit--I've realized you can't attach a scrollwheel method to the "fake" scroller....any ideas?

Comment: Added demo above.  It uses some basic javascript event handling because the mousewheel event is not cross-browser.  There are plugins for this, but the demo should show you the basics: http://jsfiddle.net/SKUQB/

Comment: Thanks again for your help! 

Out of curiosity, could you give me your opinion on this idea here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030147/appending-a-vertical-scroll-to-a-horizontal-scroll-bar?noredirect=1#comment22867936_16030147

Basically I'm trying to achieve the same, but in a slightly different way. Does that approach work or am I completely off the mark?

Also I really appreciate the help. My only problem with the implementation above has to do with some of the math. Basically resizing or adding more content to what I have is shifting things in a way I don't want.